# My React app can't send any request using Axios or any other package

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

So I came across uploading a file to S3 bucket from my react app using a node server but turns out that it will return an error like this:

```
config:
data: "{"fileName":"images/53czv-ps","fileType":"png"}"
headers: {Accept: "application/json, text/plain, */*", Content-Type: "application/json;charset=utf-8"}
maxContentLength: -1
method: "post"
timeout: 0
transformRequest: [ƒ]
transformResponse: [ƒ]
url: "https://www.mywebsite.co.uk/upload"
validateStatus: ƒ validateStatus(status)
xsrfCookieName: "XSRF-TOKEN"
xsrfHeaderName: "X-XSRF-TOKEN"
__proto__: Object
data: undefined
status: 404
```

This is the result from server in logs by using the address in browser

```
{ MissingRequiredParameter: Missing required key 'Key' in params                                                       at ParamValidator.fail (/var/www/html/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:50:37)                          
at ParamValidator.validateStructure (/var/www/html/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:61:14)             
at ParamValidator.validateMember (/var/www/html/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:88:21)                
 at ParamValidator.validate (/var/www/html/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:34:10)                      
at Request.VALIDATE_PARAMETERS (/var/www/html/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/event_listeners.js:126:42)               
at Request.callListeners (/var/www/html/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20)                   
at callNextListener (/var/www/html/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:96:12)                         
at /var/www/html/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/event_listeners.js:86:9                                                  at finish (/var/www/html/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/config.js:386:7)                                                 at /var/www/html/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/config.js:404:9                                                           message: 'Missing required key \'Key\' in params',                                                                   code: 'MissingRequiredParameter',                                                                                    time: 2020-06-16T21:22:44.190Z }
```

By using this:

```
const res = await axios.post('https://www.mywebsite.co.uk/upload', { fileName, fileType })
        .then(data => console.log('DATA', data))
        .catch(error => console.log(error.response))
```

The I found out that if I use GET it wont work either

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 404
at createAxiosError (utils.js:147)
at Object.settle (utils.js:123)
at handleRequest (handle_request.js:124)
at index.js:26
at new Promise (<anonymous>)
at MockAdapter.<anonymous> (index.js:25)
at dispatchRequest (dispatchRequest.js:52)
```

By using this:

```
await axios.get('https://community-open-weather-map.p.rapidapi.com/weather').then(res => console.log(res))
```

Any idea what it could be?

Comment: Enter you endpoint in browser directly. It seems that the url doesn't exist.

Comment: @SirajAlam It is working as I've tested in Postman and if I put the url in browser directly my server debugging console will return the error for missing parameters

Comment: Are you setting the headers in the axios config?

Comment: @ludwiguer the backend does not require so no

Comment: The `Key` param is used by AWS S3 to reference the file you upload. So you have an error in your Node app when uploading the file to S3.

Comment: @fubar if I use the GraphQL mutation in order to receive the Signed Request it's all fine but then I I want to use Axios to upload the file will crash again